# How to share same header in spring-boot REST when exception occurs

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my spring-boot application I creating response like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(object, getHeaders(request), HttpStatus.OK);

protected HttpHeaders getHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) {
}
```

problem is when exception occurs there is missing my custom headers. What is the best way to fill them ?

I found just this when I override DispatcherServlet but I dont know if this is good pattern:

```
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView processHandlerException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        response.setHeader("test", "test");
        return super.processHandlerException(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
```

Comment: _"when exception occurs there is missing my custom headers"_ What happens when an exception is thrown? Do you have exception handlers?

Comment: no I have no exception handler. I tried public class HeaderHandlerExceptionResolver extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver but with no success

Comment: Then you should add one: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice